# binding to an overloaded templated function

Tags: c++

In a totally contrived example, suppose I have two classes defined as follows

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Foo(int a) : a(a) {}

    void speak()
    {
        cout << "I am Foo(" << a << ")\n";
    }
};
```

and

```cpp
struct Bar
{
    int a, b;
    Bar(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    void speak()
    {
        cout << "I am Bar(" << a << ", " << b << ")\n";
    }
};
```

I can then define the following class for building either of these two based on the arguments passed

```cpp
template <typename T> 
struct MrMaker
{
    T make(int a) 
    {
        return T(a);
    }

    T make(int a, int b) 
    {
        return T(a, b);
    }
};
```

and do things like

```cpp
auto foo = MrMaker<Foo>::make(12);
foo.speak();

auto bar = MrMaker<Bar>::make(12, 13);
bar.speak();
```

I originally thought this worked because the instanciation of `MrMaker<Foo>` never tries to call the second overload of `make`, and likewise that of `MrMaker<Bar>` never tries to call the first overload (so not so much as SFINAE as no substitution that causes an error).

But if that's the case, why can I not write something like

```cpp
function<Foo(int)> func = std::bind(&MrMaker<Foo>::make, placeholders::_1)
```

? It seems in this case there is ambiguity about which overload is being bound. Is there an SFINAE technique or anything else that would allow this? I tried the usual recipe like

```cpp
template <typename U = T>
static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Foo, U>::value, U>::type
make(int a)
```

but received the same error.

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hdWqnWEGP)

(The original problem that "inspired" this example was attempting to template some definitions of `pybind11` wrappers for a builder class, and wanting something like `.def("make", &MrMaker<T>::make)` to work without needing to know what arguments are required for that `T`)

Comment: a [mcve], a single block of code with all necessary parts, would make it much simpler to write an answer

Comment: `auto foo = MrMaker<Foo>::make(12);` well not really. This will not compile.

Comment: @n.m. added a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hdWqnWEGP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you do not call the function it is still there. If `MrMaker` was no template you would also not be able to get a pointer to `make` without ambiguity. The solution is to pick the right overload via a cast:

```
auto f = static_cast<Bar (MrMaker<Bar>::*)(int,int)>(&MrMaker<Bar>::make);
auto g = static_cast<Foo (MrMaker<Foo>::*)(int)>(&MrMaker<Foo>::make);
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rd5s8xseM)

Alternatively, delay overload resolution to the actual call, by not using `std::bind` but a lambda:

```
auto h = [](int x) {
             return MrMaker<Foo>::make(x);
         };
```

Comment: Yep, I can certainly use a cast but I was hoping there was some mechanism for deducing the correct one.

Comment: @ChrisD this is the mechanism

Comment: Sorry deduce was a bad word, maybe "infer based on the template argument alone". The motivation was writing boilerplate for wrapping an entire templated builder class with several other methods and being able to use it without having to cast to the right overload. I did not think of using a lambda though.

Comment: @ChrisD i think you want two different speicalizations. No SFINAE needed, but just a specialization for `MrMaker<Bar>` with a `make` method and another specialization for `MrMaker<Foo>` with a different `make` method. At that point you could as well have two seperate classes rather than a template, but I suppose there is more than what you show here

Answer (score 0):

The situation with your SFINAE'd functions is filly analogous to this:

```
template <typename T = int> T foo() { return T{}; }
auto pfoo = &foo; // Won't work. Type of foo is not deduced.
```

You need to write

```
auto pfoo = &foo<int>;
```

and likewise

```
std::bind(&MrMaker<Foo>::make<Foo>, placeholders::_1)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fdr7G955T)

I would never recommend using this in production code though.